# Measuring energy required or generated in gasification

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, computational-chemistry, kinetics

The typical equation used to measure heat is as follows:

$q = mcΔT\\
\text{Where, }\\
q = \text{heat} (\pu{J}) \\
m = \text{mass} (\pu{g}) \\
c = \text{specific heat capacity} (\pu{J g^-1 K^-1})\\ 
ΔT = \text{change in temperature} (\pu{K})$

This is meant to measure the change in thermal energy (i.e. net potential energy of a system).

Gasification is a process that takes hydrocarbons (often fossil fuels) and produces carbon monoxide, hydrogen, carbon monoxide, and several other substances (as a gaseous mixture) by submitting it to a gasification agent. Sometimes oxygen is used, though other agents can be used; nonetheless, combustion does not take place. The mixture is known as syngas.

The process occurs in settings where temperature is greater than $\pu{700 °C} (\pu{973.15 K})$. However, I am not entirely certain how energy is measured — I imagine we are using changes in enthalpy.

If anyone has knowledge of this subject, please enlighten me. Gasification and syngas are espoused as alternatives to recycling and incineration (since the latter are not always environmentally friendly or economically feasible).

Comment: The cost will depend substantially on the starting material : coal and food waste would have significant differences. Depending on a specific process , carbon monoxide is commonly produced which is dangerous..

Comment: Are you aware that the equation you wrote doesn't apply to chemical reactions?

Comment: @ChetMiller Yes, I am aware. It measures the quantity of heat transferred. It’s helpful when dealing with intermolecular forces, but not with chemical reactions. That is why I brought up enthalpy—and possibly entropy. I am no expert on the subject, but I am trying to become more of an expert, so that’s why I came to stack exchange :)